# Populate Dropdown Boxes while also Populating Table

Tags: php, html, sql-server, foreach, dropdownbox

I have a table that is populated using a foreach loop. One of my columns is SKU Group, which is a column of dropdown boxes. However, whenever the foreach loop runs, only the one corresponding value for that row is displayed inside the dropdown box.

How can I get it so that I can run the foreach loop and it correctly populates the table, while the dropdowns are also populated with every SKU Group name and not just the single value that corresponds with each row?

Normally, I would just run this `foreach($var->fetchAll() as $var1)` for the dropdowns to populate them, but I dont think that it can be ran properly inside another loop that is already running. So that is why I am having this issue.

HTML Table:

```
<table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th style="display: none">Product ID</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Major Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Minor Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Description</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Status</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Create Date</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Group</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td style="display: none" class="prod_id" id="product_id-<?php echo intval ($row['Product_ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Product_ID']?></td>
            <td class="major_cat" id="major_cat-<?php echo intval ($row['Major Category'])?>"><?php echo $row['Major Category']?></td>
            <td class="minor_cat" id="minor_cat-<?php echo intval ($row['Minor Category'])?>"><?php echo $row['Minor Category']?></td>
            <td class="rep_code" id="rep_code-<?php echo intval ($row['Product Report Code'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['Product Report Code']?></td>
            <td class="sku" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['SKU']?></td>
            <td class="sku_desc" id="sku_desc-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU Description']?></td>
            <td class="sku_status" id="sku_status-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Status'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['SKU Status']?></td>
            <td class="create_date" id="create_date-<?php echo intval ($row['Date'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['Date']?></td>
            <td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Group'])?>" align="center">

                <select id="sku_group_dropdown">
                    <option
                        value=""
                        data-name="<?php echo $row ['SKU Group'];?>"
                    >
                        <?php echo $row ['SKU Group'];?>
                    </option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gosh this sure looks familiar...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372678/correctly-displaying-and-populating-dropdown-boxes-in-a-table

Comment: Yep, except I simplified my posting

Comment: Well don't disregard my comment about using parameters in your query. And sadly from this it is really difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could try putting the result of the query in an array and just doing a foreach on the array then a foreach on the array again for the select options, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

first need to populate your dropdown list using loop

```
<?php 
 $i = 0;
 $content = '';
  $names =  array('Test1','Test2');
  foreach ($names as $row) {
  if($i== 0){  
  $names =  array('Test1','Test2');// replace it  echo $row ['SKU Group'];

  foreach($names as $key)
  {
   $content .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$key.'</option>';    
  }
   } 
  $i++;
  ?>

  <tr>
   <td>sadasdsa</td>
    <td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Group'])?>" align="center">

    <select id="sku_group_dropdown">
    <?php echo $content?>
    </select>

     </td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">                  </td>
       </tr>

          <?php } ?>
```

in this code replace your array data or if you want to populate dropdown data outside your loop then first get your group data for you can use this code

Comment: i am back in the chat

Comment: I have posted my other problems in the chat room from the other post i had

Comment: drop down working ? then your page save then give me this page html

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136374/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-rataiczak24