# Enable and Disable Dropdown on HTML Button Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I currently have a multiple row and column table with one of the columns containing dropdowns and one of the rows containing an Edit/Save button. The dropdowns in each row of my table are disabled on load. However, on the button click, that dropdown in that row is then enabled. Once the button is clicked again (which is then a save button) they should then be disabled.

I have it working, but it is only working for the top row as I am using `getElementById`. Everything I have tried for classes including `getElementByClassName` is not working for me.

I have found multiple examples of what I am trying to do, but they all seem to be dealing with just one dropdown, whereas I have many that I am dealing with.

So how can I get this to successfully work so that it will work for the corresponding row in which the button is pressed and not just the first row?

HTML Table:

```
<table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th style="display: none">Product ID</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Major Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Minor Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Description</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Status</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Create Date</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Group</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td style="display: none" class="prod_id" id="product_id-<?php echo intval ($row['Product_ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Product_ID']?></td>
            <td class="major_cat" id="major_cat-<?php echo intval ($row['Major Category'])?>"><?php echo $row['Major Category']?></td>
            <td class="minor_cat" id="minor_cat-<?php echo intval ($row['Minor Category'])?>"><?php echo $row['Minor Category']?></td>
            <td class="rep_code" id="rep_code-<?php echo intval ($row['Product Report Code'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['Product Report Code']?></td>
            <td class="sku" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['SKU']?></td>
            <td class="sku_desc" id="sku_desc-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU Description']?></td>
            <td class="sku_status" id="sku_status-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Status'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['SKU Status']?></td>
            <td class="create_date" id="create_date-<?php echo intval ($row['Date'])?>" align="center"><?php echo $row['Date']?></td>
            <td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Group'])?>" align="center">

                <div>
                <select id="sku_group_dropdown" disabled>
                    <option
                        value=""
                        data-name="<?php echo $row ['SKU Group'];?>"
                    >
                        <?php echo $row ['SKU Group'];?>
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>

                <!--<div><?php echo $row ['SKU Group'];?></div>-->
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lines of JavaScript I use to switch from disabled to enabled and vice versa. These are posted in different areas of my JS, but am only posting these 2 lines as they are the only lines of code that apply to my question:

```
document.getElementById("sku_group_dropdown").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("sku_group_dropdown").disabled=true;
```

Comment: ok you want to first time disabled all drop down then when click button then want to enable it? so when you want to disable it again?

Comment: Yes, when i load the page, everything is disabled, which is what I want. Then you are correct, when I click the edit button, I want the corresponding dropdown to be enabled. Then when I click the button again (which will then be a save button), I want it be disabled again

Comment: ok wait a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this code

```html
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
     <table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th style="display: none">Product ID</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Major Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Minor Category</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Description</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Status</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Create Date</th>
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Group</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



       <tr>
         <td>Test1</td>
         <td>
            <div>
                <select  disabled class="drop-down-list">
                    <option
                        value=""
                        data-name="asdas">
                        Tesy1
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>


            </td>
            <td><input type="button" class="edit" onclick="enable_value(this)" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>

     <tr>
         <td>Test2</td>
         <td>
            <div>
                <select  disabled class="drop-down-list">
                    <option
                        value=""
                        data-name="asdas">
                        Tesy2
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>


            </td>
            <td><input type="button" class="edit" onclick="enable_value(this)" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>


     <script>
        function enable_value(event){
            if($(event).parent().parent().find('.drop-down-list').prop("disabled")){
                $(event).parent().parent().find('.drop-down-list').attr('disabled', false);
            } else {
                 $(event).parent().parent().find('.drop-down-list').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: this is demo code which just concept , you can change as you want

Comment: This seems to work, however I still need it to be disabled again once I click the button again...how would would that work and with that being the case, I wouldnt be able to use an onclick attribute for the button would I?

Comment: one thing when you click save button then add one function as like above
$(event).parent().parent().find('.drop-down-list').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but how would that work since its just one button? It is an edit/save button in one

Comment: ok you want that same button first click enable it then again click disable it?

Comment: By just testing it, this seems to work...I will try to implement it into my actual code now

Comment: ok if you find any problem then inform me and if work then give vote . ha ha ha

Comment: it works!! Thank you very much for your help...it is much appreciated!

Comment: I also have this other dropdown question if you were interested in taking a look at it....but if not, no problem at all and thanks for the help that you already provided! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375534/populate-dropdown-boxes-while-also-populating-table?noredirect=1#comment71908887_42375534

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136374/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-rataiczak24).

Comment: im back if you are still around